# Why does my print .css look correct in "Shrink to Fit," rather than 100% zoom, in Firefox and IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, printing

I've been developing print styles for my employer's site. In Chrome, everything looks correct print preview. In Firefox and Internet Explorer, however, the user is given a zoom option. If the user zooms to "Shrink to Fit," the print preview right. But at 100% zoom, everything scales bigger than the stylesheet dictates, and clips off the page.

```
body {
  font-size:100%;
}
@media print {
   body {
     font-size:12pt;
   }
}
```

How do IE and FF determine how to size elements at 100%? Is there anything I can do about it? At the least, can I prevent clipping at most reasonable zoom levels?

## Example:

Shrink to fit, looks correct:

[image: screenshot of Firefox print preview at Shrink to Fit]

100%, things clip:

[image: screenshot of Firefox print preview at 100% zoom]

Comment: Is it possible that Explorer uses a different paper size/margin compared to the other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed some widths set in `px` on the containing elements. Setting all containing elements widths in percentage widths within the print sheet achieved the intended result.